# How to restore Unity 3d?

Tags: unity

Recently I used Janitor tool to remove unused apps in ubuntu 11.10. I think I've removed some Unity specific libraries in the process. Now My screen look like plane vanila linux desktop without any unity launcher and top panel. even all unity specific effects are also gone.

- I tried enabling the Unity plugin in ccsm and then resetting the unity.
- I have tried `unity --reset`
- I have tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/77789/235

Answer (score 1):

If it is a matter of package that was uninstalled you can run this at terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it says that ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to resolve broken applications by first uninstalling it then installing the it.

Since you're most likely already running the broken ubuntu-desktop, you might best log out, use the alt-F2 key to go to a terminal window and perform the task from there:

> sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

This should at lease resolve the install error message you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this didn't help either

Answer (score 1):

I now restored the ubuntu using Installer and choosing the upgrade option. It just removed other extra programs which I had installed but My data remain intact. SO its now solved :)

Answer (score 0):

To reset Unity to its default settings, you can use `unity --reset`. Using CCSM is known to cause issues if you're not very careful and know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I tried unity --reset but it stops after the message -- Setting update "run_key"

Comment: Strange. Use Unity 2D until you can figure it out.